# Change selection mode for rotated shapes in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections

I have created a bunch of diagonal lines. When I select them I have a rotated selection box which is not what I want. Instead I want what I drew in red:

[image]

How to change the selection mode to reflect the red square?

Comment: Can I ask why does it matter that the selection is rotated?  Why are you trying to do this, or what is the ultimate goal? The reason I ask is because nobody will see it in your final work.

Comment: If i want to scale it vertically only it makes harder like this

Comment: If that's the case, can't you rotate the lines, then use a rectangle as a clipping mask?  It's just that the accepted solution to Expand is destructive.  Using a clipping mask would not be. So, you might want to consider that.

Comment: Is it easy to do a clipping mask ?

Comment: Yes its easy to do a clipping mask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are those lines made with strokes?
If so, I think choosing Object > Expand will solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

**Frame challenge:** seeing what you are needing to accomplish in your floorplan, I'd suggest an alternate workflow - instead of drawing a bunch of lines to make a hatch, use illustrator's pattern fills and make your life easier as the design iterates over time.

---

If you look at the appearance palette in this screengrab, you'll see that there's one polygon, with a pattern fill, and I've used the checkbox in the transform palette for "Transform Pattern Only" and rotated the pattern 45° to get an angled hatch - then switching back to the default "Transform Object Only" allows you to edit your poly and have the  hatch stay perfectly undisturbed.

---

Applied pattern

[image]

Transform palette, switch back to "Transform Object Only"

[image]

And transform or scale your poly with complete impugnity!

[image]

Which to be clear, allows a lot more easily flexibility to delineate, say terrazzo or polished concrete...

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If the desire is to merely have a squared-off, rectangular, bounding box.. Select the object(s) and choose `Object > Transform > Reset Bounding Box` from the menu. This will remove the rotated bounding box and replace it with a squared-off bounding box which will no longer adhere to the rotation of the objects. This means any dragging you do with the new squared bounding box will *distort* the objects.

If the goal is to keep the angled lines, but only *see* what is inside the red rectangle, a **Clipping Mask** may be easier.

Draw your lines, and then draw a rectangle above the lines indicating the area you *want* visible. Select the lines *and* this rectangle and choose `Object > Clipping Mask > Make` from the menu.

This will hide anything outside the rectangle, and provide a (squared) rectangular bounding box.